# How do I make a QR code that will directly download a PDF using IIS?

Tags: pdf, iis, download

We have brochures offering services in the front office of the company I work for. With the ongoing pandemic we want to make these available hands free. I would like to put a QR code on the brochure stand for each brochure and have users scan them to download the brochure digitally.

My initial thought was to put all the documents into a Google Cloud or AWS storage bucket and then just turn the document links into QR codes, but I was asked to do it with our current IIS web servers.

So far I have a site created and have directory browsing enabled. I have a virtual directory "docs" and have placed a pdf in the folder. However, when I navigate to "[my site url]/docs/[filename].pdf" I get an error saying the site can't be reached.

> This site can’t be reached Check if there is a typo in
> documents.spectrumhg.org. If spelling is correct, try running Windows
> Network Diagnostics. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

How do I create links directly to pdf or other documents using an IIS website? Do I need to create a web app that uses html links or is there a way to make an IIS site function like the storage buckets that are offered by hosting services?

Comment: In theory, pdf files can be viewed directly without any web application. Can you show the error that cannot be reached, it is better to include the status code and error message. Another thing is how you access the file and if the site url is a public url.

Comment: Odd thing is that I don't get an error code. I'll check on the other things though and give that information in the question too.

Comment: It would appear that the site url is not public. What setting changes that?

Comment: You need to get a public domain from domain provider so that public DNS can forward it to  the server IP.